# How to Join Conditionally to Different Tables

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to play around with tableau server's data and I'm trying to join the `tasks` table with `datasources` table and `workbooks` table. The `tasks` table has two important fields do this:

- `Obj_id` and
- `Obj_type`.

If `Obj_type = "Datasource"` I'd join on `datasources.id = tasks.obj_id`. If `Obj_type = "Workbook"`, I'd join on `workbook.id = tasks.obj_id`.

I tried something like this but I can't get it to work, what is the correct way to write this without retrieving nulls in my results.

```
select * from datasources d
left join workbooks w on d.parent_workbook_id = w.id
left join tasks t on (if t.obj_type = "Datasource" then d.id else w.id end) = t.obj_id
```

Sample expected output: Basically, tasks fields will always be populated because if the datasource resides in a workbook, the task table already knows that from obj_id and will join to the workbooks_id. If datasource is published separately on server, the tasks table will join to the datasources table. So there will always be a match.

| d.Name | w.Name | t.obj_type | other tasks fields |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SampleData0 | Null | Datasource | other tasks values |
| Sampledata1 | Wkbk1 | Workbook | other tasks values |

Comment: You need to add example tables and what you expect as output. We can guess what you mean, but it is usually easier if you have an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
select *
from tasks t left join
     datasources d 
     on t.obj_id = d.id and
        t.obj_type = 'Datasource' left join
     workbooks w
     on t.obj_id = w.id and
        t.obj_type = 'Workbook';
```

This is based on your description.  Your code has other columns.